# how to give parameters to closure in lua

Tags: lua, closures

I have the following code :

```
{

    identifier = "hand:" .. card.name,
    area = { x, y, 100, 100 },
    on_click = function()
        -- Code goes here
    end

}
```

I want to use the card variable and a reference to the object where this code is placed to modify a variable of the class with a value of the `card` variable.

So, how can I give parameters from the local context to the function who will be called in other pieces of code ?

I wish to launch the `on_click` function in an event management loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

save it when you assign the function, like this

```
{
    identifier = "hand:" .. card.name,
    area = { x, y, 100, 100 },
    on_click = function()
        local a_card = card
        print(a_card.name)
    end
}
```

Comment: The `{` and `}` in the original question were creating a table. They weren't a C mistake; that was valid Lua syntax. Unliked yours, which isn't.

Comment: I don't completly understand how the variables scope works, but `card` is accessible from the `on_click` function even it is called in another place.

Comment: You do not need to "save it", you can use `card` directly from the `on_click` function, since it appears it is a local variable in outer scope (outside the `{}`). Lua uses full lexical scoping, this means that your function (essentially a [closure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_science)) can use any local variables from outer scopes, even after the scope ends and the function is kept as a reference (common for callbacks, handlers).

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly, you want to be able to reference from on_click handler the object that `on_click` handler belongs to. To do this, you need to split the statement you have:

```
local card = { name = "my card" }
local object = {
  identifier = "hand:" .. card.name,
  area = { x, y, 100, 100 },
}
object.on_click = function()
  -- Code goes here
  -- you can reference card and object here (they are upvalues in this context)
  print(card.name, object.area[3])
end
object.click()
```

You can also define `on_click` a bit differently; in this case you get `object` as implicitly declared `self` variable (note that you call it a bit differently too):

```
function object:on_click()
  -- Code goes here
  -- you can reference card and object here
  print(card.name, self.area[3])
end
object:click() -- this is the same as object.click(object)
```